# left justified bold and not italic header

Tags: header-footer

I am using `\documentclass{article}` to write a paper. I have to write a header left justified, bold, font size 12 pt and not italic. Also with the page numbers in the right.

How can I have this?

It is something like this:

[image]

I have tried this

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr, blindtext}
\fancyhf{conference}
\fancyhead[L]{\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont \rightmark}
\fancyhead[L]{\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[L]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}‎
```

but it is not at the top of the 1st page and not in the left. 
Also I tried this

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}‎‎
‎\pagestyle‎{fancy}‎
\lhead{conference}‎
\rhead{\thepage}
```

But it is in italic.

I tried this as dear Kumar said, with some changes, but it has not the header on next other pages
‎

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}‎‎‎
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{authblk} ‎
\usepackage{geometry}‎
\usepackage{caption} ‎
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf,labelsep=period} 
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=30mm,
 right=30mm,
 top=25mm,
 bottom=25mm,
 }‎‎‎‎‎
\usepackage{fancyhdr}‎
\fancyhf{}‎
\lhead{\bfseries  Some conference}‎
\rhead{\thepage}‎
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}   %% default‎
      \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}‎
%% If you want headers in first page also do the following‎
\fancypagestyle{plain}{‎
\fancyhf{}‎
\lhead{\bfseries Some conference}‎
\rhead{\thepage}        %% or \rfoot??‎
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}   %% default‎
      \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}‎
}‎
‎‎
‎
‎\usepackage{graphicx} % inserting images‎‎‎p

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}‎
\renewcommand\rmdefault{ptm}‎
\usepackage{textcase,url,titlesec}‎
\titleformat{\section}{\relax}‎
                                {\large\BoldAllcaps{\thesection}}{1em}{\large\BoldAllcaps}‎‎
                                ‎‎
\newcommand{\BoldAllcaps}[1]{\MakeTextUppercase{\scshape\bfseries #1}}‎
\makeatletter‎
\renewcommand\@maketitle{%‎
\newpage‎
\null‎
 \vskip 2em%‎
 \begin{center}%‎
 \let \footnote \thanks‎
 {\Large\bfseries \@title \par}%‎
  \vskip 1.5em%‎
 {\large‎
  \lineskip .5em%‎
 \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%‎
  \@author‎
 \end{tabular}\par}%‎
 \vskip 1em%‎
 {\small \@date}%‎
 \end{center}%‎
 \par‎‎
  \vskip 1.5em}%‎
 \renewenvironment{abstract}{\section*{\abstractname}}{\relax}‎
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\par\vspace{.5em}\noindent{\large\bfseries \keywordsname:} #1\par}‎
\def\keywordsname{Keywords}‎
 \makeatletter‎‎

\title{some title}‎‎‎
‎\author{some author1}‎‎
\affil{some aff1}‎‎‎
‎\author{some author2}‎
\affil{some aff2‎}‎
\date{}‎‎
\setcounter{Maxaffil}{0}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\itshape\small}‎‎
‎
‎

 \begin{document}‎
 \maketitle‎‎
 ‎
 ‎\blinddocument‎
 ‎\end{document}‎
```

Comment: By "header", you mean the header line at the top of the page, right? What's supposed to be *in* the header (other than the page number, which is supposed to go on the right): your name, the title of the paper, the title of the current section, some fixed string, or something else?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). This will help to both clarify your question and encourage people to help you. (Almost) all questions should include an MWE.

Comment: @Mico yes I mean the line at the top of the page, It is a fixed string, the name of the conference, with a line underneath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[margin=1in,headheight=16pt,headsep=0.1in,heightrounded]{geometry}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\bfseries \textcolor{black!50}{Some conference}}
\rhead{\textcolor{black!50}{\thepage}}        %% or \rfoot??
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}   %% default
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

%% If you want headers in first page also do the following
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\bfseries \textcolor{black!50}{Some conference}}
\rhead{\textcolor{black!50}{\thepage}}        %% or \rfoot??
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}   %% default
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}

\title{Some paper}
\author{unknown}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagestyle{fancy}‎
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: and if I don't need the footer?

Comment: I don't know why the header for the second page does not appear! the first page has it

Comment: I think there is a problem with my other commands

Comment: I added mu full code as an mwe

Comment: thank you so much, is there any way to make this header gray?

Comment: could you please add it to your code? I got some error

Comment: @user3482383 Added.